# gulp dev cant be run because of mistake

Tags: node.js, gulp

I run npm install in the project's root and then when I try to run gulp de, I get the following mistake:

```
$ gulp dev
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/public/public-utils'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ente\node_modules\browser-sync\index.js:9:21)
  at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ente\gulpfile.js:27:21)
  at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at Liftoff.handleArguments   (C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
  at Liftoff.<anonymous>   (C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js    :193:16)
  at module.exports  (C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\flagged-     respawn\index.js:17:3)
  at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:185:9)
  at C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:    159:9
  at C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:108:14
  at C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:36:12
  at C:\Users\Man\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:47:7
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  at Module.runMain (module.js:577:11)
  at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
  at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

[the gulp file](https://gist.github.com/elhobbit/40e6c486e54f1eadc2d5c12c0cb314be)

i tried different things, like to go to an older node, to the latest one, reinstalled node, npm and gulp billions of times, but it didnt help.

What can it be and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post what the `gulp dev` task looks like?

Comment: here its 
https://gist.github.com/elhobbit/40e6c486e54f1eadc2d5c12c0cb314be

Comment: Can you try running `gulp build`, `gulp watch` and `gulp serve` one at a time to see which one causes the error? It looks like it's probably the browserSync stuff in `gulp serve`. If so, I'd try commenting different portions in that task to narrow it down at least.

Comment: Oh also, could you add that gist to your question?

Comment: I've ran the tasks separately, and each of them - ie build, watch and serve prints out the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to happen when you require the `browser-sync` module in your gulpfile. The module doesn't find one of it's own components `./lib/public/public-utils` and can't start.

I'd first check in your node_modules directory to see what's going on with [browser-sync](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/blob/master/index.js).
It's usually a corrupted install of the module.

Make sure that in your package.json you have browser-sync listed with the most up-to-date version (2.13.0) and to get a fresh install delete your `node_modules` directory, `npm cache clean`
 and run `npm install` again.